# JSP multiple checkbox with URL redirecting

Tags: java, jsp

This is what im trying to make:

Index.jsp:

- Form with 3 checkbox: Facebook, Instargam, Google for example. When the user selects one or more options, a new page opens with a display of what he has chosen and a link to those pages.
  For example If the user has selected Facebook and Instagram, the new page should show: You have selected Facebook and Instagram, so that when the user clicks on Facebook it is transferred to the Facebook page.

This is my `index.jsp`

```
<form action="forma.jsp" method="GET">
        <input type="checkbox" name="site" value="Facebook">Facebook<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="site" value="Instagram">Instagram<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="site" value="Google">Google<br/>
        Input name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

And `form.jsp`

```
<%
        String site = "";
        String[] sites = request.getParameterValues("site");
        if (sites != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sites.length; ++i) {
                if (sites[i].equals("Facebook")) {
                    site = "Facebook";
                }
                if (sites[i].equals("Instagram")) {
                    site = "Instagram";
                }
                if (sites[i].equals("Google")) {
                    site = "Google";
                }
                out.println("You picked: " + site);
            }
        }
    %>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to introduce it with links. To be printed on the new page, you have chosen Facebook and Instagram and by clicking on one of those two I can be transferred to their page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to do it. A simple way is to append the selected options in a `StringBuilder` object and display its content at the end of the loop as shown below:

```
<%
    String site = "";
    String[] sites = request.getParameterValues("site");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (sites != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sites.length; ++i) {
            if (sites[i].equals("Facebook")) {
                sb.append("<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/\">Facebook</a><br>");
            }
            if (sites[i].equals("Instagram")) {
                sb.append("<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/\">Instagram</a><br>");
            }
            if (sites[i].equals("Google")) {
                sb.append("<a href=\"https://www.google.com/\">Google</a><br>");
            }           
        }
        out.println("You picked: <br>" + sb);
    }
%>
```

**A sample output:**
[image]